# Understanding difference between calling function with double parentheses and two finctions

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand how debounce work. In one of the tutorials in the internet I found codel ike this:

```
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const defaultText = document.getElementById("default");
const debounceText = document.getElementById("debounce");

const updateDebounceText = debounce(
  (text) => (debounceText.textContent = text),
  250
);

input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  defaultText.textContent = e.target.value;
  updateDebounceText(e.target.value);
});

function debounce(callback, delay = 1000) {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => callback(...args),delay);
  };
}
```

And here comes my question. Why do I need to create explicit variable for calling this function? Can't I simply call debounce in Event Listener? I tried doing something like this:

```
debounce((text) => (debounceText.textContent = text), 2500)(e.target.value);
```

However it would not work and fire every time I enter new value (with slight delay ,but it wasn't the delay I enter so I am guessing it simply takes some time to run this code)

Comment: "but it wasn't the delay I enter"... Wait a second. You changed original `250` to `2500` (so that is 2.5 seconds delay). So, it is you who increased the interval and delay

Comment: I mean I changed it for many different values and it always just had like 0,1s delay no matter what value I entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't, it'll work differently.

Debounce function create a timer and stores it inside the closure.
Every time you call 'debounced' function it clear previous `setTimeout` before runs new one.
In terms of user expirience it looks like function won't run until you stop doing something.

But if you re-create the function every time you'll just lose previous timer.
It means that previously started `setTimeout` will be fired because you haven't cleared it.

Comment: Ohh so `updateDebounceText` is a variable containing reference to specific instance of debounce function? So next time someone enters a character same function is ran but with different arguments? Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: @AlexiejStiukov yes, you got the concept right